# Ubuntu Server 20.04 freezes after a few hours if no monitor connected

Tags: 18.04, server, 20.04

I'm having this problem from ubuntu 18.04 (now upgraded to 20.04).

I've bought this mini pc:
SeeKool Z83-V
Intel Atom x5-Z8350 Processor
4GB Ram
64GB Rom
Graphics HD 400
1000Mbps LAN
4K MINI
USB 3.0
HDMI+VGA Outputs

I wanted to use it in my home LAN, with home bridge, pihole and some other stuff.

So after a clean install of ubuntu server (with both edition the problem is the same) I started with PiHole.

everything worked great for 4-5 hours, then the ubuntu server (I've used as a headless machine) became unresponsive. In system log I've not found nothing strange, it simply stops without any strange log entry.

I removed PiHole but the problem was still here, so I tried to update from 18.04 to 20.04 but nothing changed.

Even without any sort of load ubuntu became unresponsive after a few hour.

The other day I've had an idea, and I've connected a VGA monitor to my ubuntu server. Now are 3 days that ubuntu server run smoothly.

Yesterday I've installed PiHole and HomeBridge, and it still working without any problem.

Can someone help me to find out why it has this strange behaviour?

Comment: Just to confirm that I see this behaviour too, on a mini Celeron PC. If the monitor is connected (via HDMI) then the PC runs indefinitely, even if I switch off and disconnect the monitor. But if I boot without the monitor connected, then Linux just stops after a while (maybe an hour, or two). This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04, with all available updates installed.

Comment: Glad to see I’m not the only one with this problem. 
I solved with a dummy vga home made

Comment: @Shalashaska, can you explain your comment more?  Did you build some hardware?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Server — or any other version/flavour of Ubuntu — does not require a monitor, keyboard, or mouse to operate. I have dozens of servers running Ubuntu and exactly zero of them have a monitor connected unless something is really, really wrong. That said, a BIOS *might* care.

Check the BIOS settings the next time you reboot to see if you can tell the machine to run “headless”. What’s probably happening is that the machine waits a certain amount of time without a monitor then shuts itself down, thinking it’s not being used. This is generally the case with consumer-grade hardware.

Hope this points you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you Matigo! You were right! the problem was the headless mode.

Unfortunately the bios didn't have any sort of option, but I've used an old "trick" using 3 resistors connected to the VGA port to simulate the presence of a monitor and it works very good without any problem!!

Thank you for the input!!!

Comment: It might be covered by power/energy saving setting in the BIOS.

Comment: You’re right, but in my bios there isn’t a setting for power or energy saving :-(

Comment: In that case, you'll need to spend about $6 USD for a HDMI Dummy Plug (also called a "Headless Ghost"). This will have the computer believe there is a monitor connected to the machine.

Comment: @Shalashaska oh well. Just in case it helps, my BIOS power settings where 'hidden' under the ACPI menu. ACPI is Advanced Configuration and Power Interface. This worked for me, so thanks Matigo for mentioning this possibility!